# Why does a call to `str(someList)` sometimes create an "array" of spaces?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

`playerList` contains two `Player` objects (with `str` attributes called, respectively, `"a"` and `"b"`), and `Player` implements `__str__` and `__repr__`. When I concatenate `str(playerList)` onto another string, I expect the string to be appended by something of the form `"[a, b]"`. Instead, the resulting string is appended by `"[ , ]"`. What mistake am I making that gives this result?

Here's what I wrote

`prompt = "And then choose the opponent you would like to attack from " + str(playerList)`

```
def __str__ (self):
    return self.name

def __repr__ (self):
    return str()
```

What I get on stdout:

```
"And then choose the opponent you would like to attack from [, ]"
```

What I want:

```
"And then choose the opponent you would like to attack from [a,b]"
```

Comment: return str() ? Shouldn't be self.__str__ ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hope the update was good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `__repr__` method returns an empty string:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str()
```

`str()` with no arguments is an empty string:

```
>>> str()
''
```

If you wanted to call `__str__` do so directly, or pass `self` to `str()`:

```
return self.__str__()
```

or

```
return str(self)
```

Note that converting a list to a string will include all strings in that list as their *representation*; the output of `repr(stringobject)`, which uses the same notation you'd use when creating such a string. The list `['a', 'b']` is going to be converted to a string using exactly that notation:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b']
>>> l
['a', 'b']
>>> str(l)
"['a', 'b']"
>>> print str(l)
['a', 'b']
```

If you really wanted to include those strings *without* quotes, you'll need to do your own formatting:

```
>>> '[{}]'.format(', '.join([str(elem) for elem in l]))
'[a, b]'
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join([str(elem) for elem in l]))
[a, b]
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain that when the interpreter displays a list, it displays the repr of each item of the list, thus `[, ]` for a two-element list.

Comment: And that's what I said :)

Comment: @Robᵩ: yup, but my shuttle arrived at my stop so I had to get out and walk for a short while first. :-)